# Как проще отрисовать круг через <path> SVG?

Tags: svg

Paths в SVG - универсальный и мощный инструмент. Но вот отрисовать в нем такую фигуру как круг - задача не такая и простая. Казалось бы есть A (Arc), но я лично смог нарисовать круг только с помощью двух дуг. При этом центр круга нигде не указан, он лежит по середине конечных точек этих дуг. Для контроля добавил белую линию.

```html
<svg width="600" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M40 100 A 50 50 0 0 1 140 100
                     A 50 50 0 0 1 40 100"
       stroke="black" fill="rgb(180,180,255)"/>        
    <line x1="40" y1="100" x2="140" y2="100" stroke="white"/>
</svg>
```

Можно нарисовать круг с помощью двух кубических Безье. Примерно круг в моем случае))

```html
<svg width="320" height="320" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M40 100 C 40 34 140 34 140 100
                     C 140 166 40 166 40 100"
       stroke="black" fill="rgb(180,180,255)"/>        
    <line x1="40" y1="100" x2="140" y2="100" stroke="white"/>
</svg>
```

**Есть ли способ нарисовать круг проще именно с помощью строки `path`, так чтобы она состояла из одной кривой?**

Comment: Нет, или я такого не знаю. Две дуги это самое простое и понятное из того что я видел

Comment: @AlexeyTen по идее же одной должно хватать, почти целый круг можно отрисовать, а если конечной точкой указать начальную, то ничего не рисуется. Или я что-то не так делал...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласен с комментарием от **@Alexey Ten**

> Нет, или я такого не знаю. Две дуги это самое простое и понятное из
> того что я видел

Ответил бы точно так же.
Мотивация вопроса понятна, так как `animateMotion`, например не работает с `circle`, а только с `path`, реализующий форму круга.

### Не знаю, будет ли проще решение с помощью векторного редактора

Итак по шагам:

- В векторном редакторе, наример `Inkscape` выбираем в боковом меню инструмент - *рисовать круги, эллипсы* и удерживая shift рисуете из центра круг.
  Сохраняете файл и копируете формулу `path`

Но, вам никогда не удастся нарисовать идеальный круг, он будет иметь, хоть немного форму эллипса с разными `rx` и `ry`

***Другой способ***

- Пишите файл svg с нужными координатами центра и размером радиуса
  окружности

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300" >  
    <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100" fill="none" stroke="black" />  
</svg>
```

- Загружаете этот файл в векторный редактор и выбираете в верхнем меню
  **Контур / Оконтурить объект** -   **<kbd>Shift + Ctrl + C</kbd>**
  Сохраняете файл в формате SVG, копируете path

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
  <path fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" d="M150 50C95 50 50 95 50 150 50 205 95 251 150 251 205 251 251 205 251 150 251 95 205 50 150 50zM150 51C205 51 250 95 250 150 250 205 205 250 150 250 95 250 51 205 51 150 51 95 95 51 150 51z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Я работаю в Corel, там не сложно отрисовать правильный круг, а затем преобразовать в кривые. При этом путь формируется из 4 кубических Безье. Странно... Значит буду писать минифункцию или привыкну к отрисовке двух дуг. Подозреваю, что path создан для отображения сложных векторных контуров. А у векторов есть начало и конец, и центр круга - ни то, ни другое)). Да и круг образовывает замкнутую, а для path односложные замкнутые ни к чему. Прямоугольников же тоже нет... Ну точно)))

Comment: Согласен, вариантов то и нет. Через четыре кубических Безье не вариант, а две дуги не такое уж и страшное решение. Просто убивает шестерная взаимозависимость: четыре раза указывается радиус (!!!) и два раза прописываю диаметр (между начальной и конечной точками дуг). А повторение ни к чему хорошему не приводит))) Остается надежда на то, что можно использовать переменные для этого.

Comment: @Leonid Вот почитай почему дважды используется радиусы (rx ry) в [Дуга элипса – Elliptical Arc (A,a)](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=900)

Comment: Вот вроде получилось без повторов почти. Указываю только начальную точку, два раза радиус, угол поворота дуги, бОльшую дугу, по часовой, конечную точку - почти ту же начальную. Ничего лишнего. Кстати, не прав комментатор под статьей: при такой "супердутой" дуге разница в значении углов поворота есть. Максимальное разница достигается углом 45 с кратностью в 90 (135, 225...).

Comment: С максимальной разницей в отклонении я погорячился, если забить 30 и 31, то можно получить неожиданные результаты.

Answer (score 0):

Никак не отрисовывается круг если в качестве конечной точки указать начальную. Но можно немного сместить)) В данном случае 60 --> 60.00001 и все работает. Можно одной дугой нарисовать круг.

Так как незамкнутая фигура все равно заливается, то результат почти идеальный, глазу не различимый точно. Возможные негативные последствия незамкнутого круга можно нивелировать инструкцией замыкания `z` в конце строки пути. На отображение не повлияет, зато в векторных редакторах, наверняка, будет нормально заливаться цветом (без идеально замкнутого контура были бы ошибки заливки).

Для лучшего понимания отметил начало дуги (и почти конец ее же) красной точкой.

```html
<svg width="600" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M60 110 A 50 50 0 1 1 60.00001 110 z"
       stroke="black" fill="rgb(180,180,255)"/> 
    <circle cx="60" cy="110" r="3" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```